# OpenLayers/Geoserver cross domain problem

Tags: openlayers-2, boundless-suite

I'm using OpenLayers and OpenGeo Suite with WMS requests.The tiles load fine, but when I try to load a getFeatureInfo I get a cross domain error. I read about including crossdomain.xml in the Geoserver folder structure but I'm not sure where that is on OpenGeo Suite and couldn't get it to work.

I've also read about setting up a proxy but don't completely understand it. How would I set that up on IIS?

Comment: I read those questions but was wondering _how_ to set up the proxy on IIS? Or how to get crossdomain.xml working?

Answer (score 0):

I did a lot more research on this and finally got it to work. The Geoserver Proxy Plugin didn't work at all and a lot of the proxy scripts I found were python or cgi, which wouldn't work for me either. I ended up setting up application request routing on my IIS server by following this tutorial:
http://www.iisadmin.co.uk/?p=326&page=2

Just follow the instructions in the website.. you have to install a software (ARRv2_setup_x86_en-us.EXE file)... Just search for that in google and download according to your OS spec..Again just follow the website instructions.

After the installation just follow the below mentioned instruction..

I had to change the URL Rewrite rules. The **pattern** I used is **^geoserver/(.*)** and the Rewrite URL is

```
**http://localhost:8080/geoserver/{R:1}**.
```

and apply the rules

Works like a charm!